# how do I replace a specific character from an string

Tags: python-3.x, string, str-replace

```
def show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
    printage = '_ ' * len(secret_word)
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        for j in range(len(old_letters_guessed)):
            if secret_word[i] == old_letters_guessed[j]:
                printage = printage.replace('_', secret_word[i])
    print(printage)

show_hidden_word('house', ['s', 'p', 'j', 'i', 'm', 'k'])
```

this is a part of a bigger HangMan mission I was told to do for school
I just can't understand how do I change printage[i] to secret_word[i]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```py
my_string = 'hello'
my_string = list(my_string)
my_string[2] = 'e'
my_string = ''.join(my_string)

print(my_string)
```

Output:

```py
heelo
```

Comment: You see I need to get the placement of the char and it had to come from the user/object that summoned the function